# SQL Select Vs Binary Search

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq, search

just for the sake of documentation for future questions i am adding 
extraction of the data to datagridview, i know the code is far from being crystal clear its just for understanding the properties of this topic.

```
    CreateDataTable(Me.t, "SELECT * FROM tblContacts", "tblContacts")
    CreateDataTable(Me.t2, "SELECT * FROM ContactsData", "ContactsData")

    Dim joined = From row1 In t.AsEnumerable()
                   Join row2 In t2.AsEnumerable()
                   On row1.Field(Of Int32)("ID") Equals row2.Field(Of Int32)("ID")
                   Select BothRows = New With {row1, row2}






    With DataGridView1
        .Columns.Clear()
        .Rows.Clear()
        ' add columns of tblContacts table
        For i = 0 To joined.AsEnumerable.First.row1.Table.Columns.Count - 1
            .Columns.Add(joined.AsEnumerable.First.row1.Table.Columns(i).ColumnName.ToString, joined.AsEnumerable.First.row1.Table.Columns(i).ColumnName.ToString)
        Next
        ' add columns of ContactsData table
        For i = 0 To joined.AsEnumerable.First.row2.Table.Columns.Count - 1
            .Columns.Add(joined.AsEnumerable.First.row2.Table.Columns(i).ColumnName.ToString, joined.AsEnumerable.First.row2.Table.Columns(i).ColumnName.ToString)
        Next
        ' add rows to datagridview
        .Rows.Add((joined.Count - 1))

    End With

    Dim rownum As Integer = 0
    For Each x In joined

        Dim row1 As DataRow = x.row1
        Dim row2 As DataRow = x.row2

        ' populate data to dgv
        For i = 0 To row1.Table.Columns.Count - 1
            DataGridView1.Rows(rownum).Cells(i).Value = row1.Item(i).ToString
        Next

        For i = row1.Table.Columns.Count To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
            DataGridView1.Rows(rownum).Cells(i).Value = row2.Item(i - row1.Table.Columns.Count).ToString
        Next

        rownum += 1
    Next
```

---

after testing @ Tim`s answer below:
ive made a test for linq to dataset but i get an error and i cant figure out why..
the error description is 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source'
just in case i have tested a regular SQL inner join query and its working fine.

i created 2 tables in access this are the tables

```
 tblCOntacts
 --------------
 ID FirstName   LastName
 ---------------------------------
 22 John        Smith
 23 Jane        Apple
 24 Jonathan    Tucker


 ContactsData
 --------------
 ID Proffesion  Hoby
 ---------------------------------
 22 Carpenter   Long Runs
 23 Pilot       Gym
 24 Psychologyst    Programming
```

Here is my code, i commented the line that derive the error:

```
 Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)           Handles Button4.Click
     CreateDataTable(Me.t, "SELECT * FROM tblContacts", "tblContacts")
    CreateDataTable(Me.t2, "SELECT * FROM ContactsData", "ContactsData")

   Dim joined = From row1 In t.AsEnumerable()
                  Join row2 In t2.AsEnumerable()
                  On row1.Field(Of Int32)("ID") Equals row2.Field(Of Int32)("ID") ' here i get the error: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source
                  Select BothRows = New With {row1, row2}

    For Each x In joined
        Dim row1 As DataRow = x.row1
        Dim row2 As DataRow = x.row2
    Next
 end sub


   Public con As OleDbConnection
   Public dset As DataSet
   Public ad As OleDbDataAdapter
   Public cmd As OleDbCommand
   Public t As DataTable
Public t2 As DataTable

  Private Sub CreateDataTable(ByVal tb As DataTable, ByVal query As String,   ByVal table As String)
         Dim q As String = query
    con = New OleDbConnection
    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Jonathan\Desktop\בסיס נתונים access\AddressBook.mdb"

    con.Open()
    dset = New DataSet
    cmd = New OleDbCommand(query, con)
    ad = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
    ad.Fill(dset, table)
    con.Close()

    ' query dataset with linq
    tb = dset.Tables(table)
 end sub
```

---

i have 2 dataTables from different Access dataBases(so i can not use SQL join steatments), i need to match 2 columns from records from the 2 tables trough the same numeric primary key.
i am considering 2 options:

1. multiple SQL SELECT Queries.
2. binary search on the 2 datatable objects with visual basic.

what way is more efficient? more professional? what is the proper way to do that?

tanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach in terms of efficiency and - more important - readability and maintainability is to use [`Linq-To-DataSet`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552415(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Dim joined = From row1 In table1.AsEnumerable()
             Join row2 In table2.AsEnumerable()
             On row1.Field(Of Int32)("ID") Equals row2.Field(Of Int32)("ID")
             Select BothRows = New With {row1, row2}

For Each x In joined
    Dim row1 As DataRow = x.row1
    Dim row2 As DataRow = x.row2
Next
```

You need to add `Imports System.Linq`. [`Enumerable.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.join(v=vs.100).aspx) is efficient since it uses a set.

Comment: OK its time to get into linq...thank you @tim i will use that method.

Comment: after testing the suggestion i am struggling some error... the description was edited in my original question. i will be thankful for some help.

Comment: @Jonathan: you cannot initialize the datatable  in CreateDataTable in this way since the paramezer is not ByRef, actually you are only initializing a local variable. I wozld suggest to return this table from the method, therefore make it a Function. Of course you could also assign the fields t and t1 in this method.

Comment: tnx! now its working perfect, last question, how can i extract rows count/columns count from the variable joined? i didnt found any property for that

Comment: Joined is just the name of the variable that holds a sequence of an anonymous type with two properties row1 and row2. So you can use a loop like a For Each to enumerate them as I've shown above. If you wanta collection you could use Joined.ToList or ToArray. If you just want the count use Joined.Count().

Comment: OK found those properties for example: joined.Last.row1.Item(0), joined.LongCount, joined.Count.

Comment: Yes, but LongCount and Count are not properties but extention methods in the Enumerable class. They will execute this deferred executed Linq query always. So, if you need the Count value multiple times store it in a variable or materialize the query with ToLIist. Otherwise it is very inefficient if you execute the query always. Google deferred execution to understand tge concept of Linq queries.